# Session 'app': Changes were not applied. Adding or renaming a resource requires an application restart

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

As I am new to Android and I am working on an app, but I've got a problem and I do not know how to fix it.

Here is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an error, it just warns you that you need to reinstall the app and restart to see the changes.

You can click reinstall and restart the app and it will do that.